# PHP form does not seem to be sending

Tags: php, forms, contact-form

I have the following HTML:

```
 <form id="enquiryform" name="enquiryform" action="contact.php" method="post" >
        <table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="4" align="left">
        <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><input name="efcontactname" type="text" class="fields" value=""  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Company Name</td>
        <td><input name="efcompanyname" type="text" class="fields" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Postcode</td>
        <td><input name="efpostcode" type="text" class="fields" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Telephone Number</td>
        <td><input name="eftel" type="text" class="fields" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Email Address</td>
        <td><input name="efemailaddress" class="fields" type="text" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Re:</td>
        <td>
        <select name="efenquirytype">
        <option value="">Please indicate the nature of your enquiry</option>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
        <option value="Hire">Hire</option>
        <option value="Parts">Parts</option>
        <option value="Service">Service</option>
        <option value="General">General</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Comments</td>
        <td><textarea name="efcomments" class="fields"class="fields" cols="30" rows="4"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Enquiry" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

and the following php within contact.php:

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "$email";
$EmailTo = "myemail@mydomain.com";
$Subject = "Website Enquiry";
    $name     = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['efcontactname']));

    $company  = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['efcompanyname']));

    $postcode = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['efpostcode']));

    $phone    = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['eftel']));

    $email    = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['efemailaddress']));

    $re       = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['efenquirytype']));

    $comments = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['efcomments']));

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Company: ";
$Body .= $company;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Postcode: ";
$Body .= $postcode;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Phone: ";
$Body .= $phone;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Re: ";
$Body .= $re;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Comments: ";
$Body .= $comments;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
}
?>
```

Obviously, I have changed the email to variable so that isn't the reason I'm not receiving it. Can anyone shed some light on where I have gone wrong? I was wondering if the dropdown menu could be causing it to fail yet give me a success message? This is the third php script I have tried and thus far none have sent the post data to my email. I have allowed a few hours between changing the php scripts as I know they can arrive delayed but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You checked spam folder?

Try send mail to address on this website: https://www.mail-tester.com/

It will show you ( if receives ) what you should change in your email configuration, what you should add ( headers ) etc. because mail servers have filters. Your sending email can be just wrong :)

Comment: I have checked my spam and tried multiple accounts (personal domains, hotmail etc). Will give the site a go

Comment: strangely the website receives the messages and I have a score of 6.7

Comment: So, you should check on website, what is wrong. DCMA certification, right headers etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using localhost?

The mail() function in PHP won't work in localhost.

Try adding this:

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

It enables errors in php if not enabled using

Comment: Try checking the Spam Box for the email you sent it to

Comment: Use $body = wordwrap($body);

Answer (score 0):

There are two minor mistakes you need to fix.mistakes are given below:

**$Body .= $name;** instead of **$Body .= $Name;**

**$EmailFrom = "email";** instead of **$EmailFrom = "$email";**

Note:`put $email to email or give some value to variable $email`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using microsoft windows system it will not send the emails. As it has no a email system installed.

If you are using linux system make sure you have installed a email server software

If you are sure that all these two works, try remove if statement from mail()

Just do like this

```
<?php
if (mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>")){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.html\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
}
?>
```

Also check without if statement if it works.

Don't forgot checking SPAM box in your email account.
If sender domain A DNS entry don't matchs server's IP where php file is hosted mail message will go to SPAM folder.

Also check if your server IP is not blacklisted